# How to test custom assertions in QUnit

Tags: javascript, qunit

I would like to test custom assertions that I've written for QUnit. On the [QUnit home page](http://qunitjs.com/) it says it can [test its own assertions](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/test/main/assert.js), but it only shows how to test that assertions pass. Ie it doesn't seem to test conditions where an assertion should fail. Is there any way to sort of capture a fail, and have it result in a passed test?

Say I wanted to test [this custom assertion](http://api.qunitjs.com/pushResult/):

```
QUnit.assert.mod2 = function( value, expected, message ) {
    var actual = value % 2;
    this.pushResult( {
        result: actual === expected,
        actual: actual,
        expected: expected,
        message: message
    } );
};
```

The above assertion might be used like so:

```
QUnit.test( "mod2", function( assert ) {
    assert.mod2( 2, 0, "2 % 2 == 0" );
    assert.mod2( 3, 1, "3 % 2 == 1" );
});
```

So I'd want to write a test to assert that the mod2 test works as expected.

The [tests for QUnit assertions](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/test/main/assert.js) have the following which tests that the `.ok()` assertion passes when expected:

```
QUnit.test( "ok", function( assert ) {
    assert.ok( true );
    assert.ok( 1 );
    assert.ok( "1" );
    assert.ok( Infinity );
    assert.ok( {} );
    assert.ok( [] );
} );
```

But how might I test when the assertion fails successfully? The test might look something like this:

```
QUnit.test( "test assert.mod2", function( assert ) {
    assert.mod2( 2, 0, "2 % 2 == 0" );
    assert.fails (assert.mod2( 2, 1, "2 % 2 == 0" ));
    assert.mod2( 3, 1, "3 % 2 == 1" );
    assert.fails (assert.mod2( 3, 0, "3 % 2 == 1" ));
});
```

I have made up `.fails()` to demonstrate what the test might look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like so, as per the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/test/main/assert.js):

```
QUnit.module( "failing assertions", {
    beforeEach: function( assert ) {
        var originalPushResult = assert.pushResult;
        assert.pushResult = function( resultInfo ) {

            // Inverts the result so we can test failing assertions
            resultInfo.result = !resultInfo.result;
            originalPushResult( resultInfo );
        };
    }
} );

QUnit.test( "ok", function( assert ) {
    assert.ok( false );
    assert.ok( 0 );
    assert.ok( "" );
    assert.ok( null );
    assert.ok( undefined );
    assert.ok( NaN );
} );
```